# Flash ActionScript 3.0 Unload SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

so I want to unload my 1st SWF before load 2nd SWF
my problem when I load SWF is 2nd SWF is stack with 1st SWF
and when I back from 2nd SWF to 1ST sound play will Stack too
and 1st SWF's animation can still seen on 2nd SWF

1St.SWF Code:

```
var pausePoint:Number = 0.00;
var aPlaying:Boolean;
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("home.mp3"));

soundChannel = sound.play(0,999);
aPlaying = true;    
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    addChild(loader);
    
    btnInfo.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, loadInfo);
    function loadInfo(event : MouseEvent): void{
        removeChild(loader);
        loader.unloadAndStop();
        var SWFRequestInfo:URLRequest = new URLRequest("2nd.swf");
        loader.load(SWFRequestInfo);
        addChild(loader);
    }
```

2nd.SWF Code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);

btnBack.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, loadBack);
function loadBack(event : MouseEvent): void{
    removeChild(loader);
    loader.unloadAndStop();
    var SWFRequestBack:URLRequest = new URLRequest("1st.swf");
    loader.load(SWFRequestBack);
    addChild(loader);
}
```

its there any solution to solve this problem?

## Updated 2

//main.swf

```
    const FIRST:int = 1;
const SECOND:int = 2;
var current:int;
var loader1:Loader = new Loader();
var loader2:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader1);
addChild(loader2);
addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD_SWF, loadSWF);
trace("first Load");
loader2.visible=false;
loader1.visible=false;
loader1.load(new URLRequest("1.swf"));
loader1.visible=true;
current=FIRST;

function loadSWF(event:LoadEvent):void
{
    if(current == FIRST){
        current=SECOND;
        loader2.load(new URLRequest(event.url));
        loader2.visible=true;
        trace("loader2 Loaded");
        loader1.unloadAndStop(true);
        loader1.visible=false;
        trace("loader1 Unloaded");
    }
    else{
        current=FIRST;
        loader1.load(new URLRequest(event.url));
        loader1.visible=true;
        trace("loader1 Loaded");
        loader2.unloadAndStop(true);
        loader2.visible=false;
        trace("loader2 Unloaded");
    }
    
}
```

1.swf

```
function clickNext(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("next clicked");
    dispatchEvent(new LoadEvent(LoadEvent.LOAD_SWF, "2.swf"));
}
```

2.swf

```
function clickPrev(event:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("prev clicked");
    dispatchEvent(new LoadEvent(LoadEvent.LOAD_SWF, "1.swf"));
}
```

LoadEvent.as

```
package  {
    import flash.events.Event;  
    public class LoadEvent extends Event {
        
        public static const LOAD_SWF:String = "LoadSWF";
        
        public var url:String;
        
        public function LoadEvent(type:String, url:String,bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false) {
            super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
            this.url=url;
        }    
        
        public override function clone():Event
        {
            return new LoadEvent(type,url,bubbles,cancelable );
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make 3-rd (main) SWF which will loads/unloads the 1-st and the 2-nd SWF. When you click at the `btnBack` or `btnInfo` you can dispatch some event. This event you can catch in the main SWF and unload current SWF and load next SWF.

**UPDATE**

This is a code of the main SWF:

```
const FIRST:int = 1;
const SECOND:int = 2;
var current:int;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedHandler);
addChild(loader);
loadFirst();

function loadedHandler(event:Event):void
{
    loader.content.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
}

function closeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (current == FIRST)
    {
        loadSecond();
    }
    else if (current == SECOND)
    {
        loadFirst();
    }
}

function loadFirst():void
{
    if (loader.content)
    {
        loader.unloadAndStop(true);
    }
    current = FIRST;
    loader.load(new URLRequest("1st.swf"));
}

function loadSecond():void
{
    if (loader.content)
    {
        loader.unloadAndStop(true);
    }
    current = SECOND;
    loader.load(new URLRequest("2nd.swf"));
}
```

The next code is dispatched from the 1-st and the 2-nd SWF in the MouseEvent.CLICK handler:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CLOSE));
```

**UPDATE #2**

```
const FIRST:int = 1;
const SECOND:int = 2;
var current:int;

var loader1:Loader = new Loader();
var loader2:Loader = new Loader();
loader1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded1Handler);
loader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded2Handler);
addChild(loader1);
addChild(loader2);

loadFirst();

function loaded1Handler(event:Event):void
{
    loader1.content.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
    loader2.visible = false;
}

function loaded2Handler(event:Event):void
{
    loader2.content.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
    loader1.visible = false;
}

function closeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (current == FIRST)
    {
        loadSecond();
    }
    else if (current == SECOND)
    {
        loadFirst();
    }
}

function loadFirst():void
{
    if (loader1.content)
    {
        loader1.unloadAndStop(true);
    }
    current = FIRST;
    loader1.load(new URLRequest("1.swf"));
    loader1.visible = true;
}

function loadSecond():void
{
    if (loader2.content)
    {
        loader2.unloadAndStop(true);
    }
    current = SECOND;
    loader2.load(new URLRequest("2.swf"));
    loader2.visible = true;
}
```

**UPDATE #3**

```
const FIRST:int = 1;
const SECOND:int = 2;
var current:int;
var loader1:Loader = new Loader();
var loader2:Loader = new Loader();

loader1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader1Compl);
loader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader2Compl);

addChild(loader1);
addChild(loader2);
addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD_SWF, loadSWF);
trace("first Load");
loader2.visible=false;
loader1.visible=false;
loader1.load(new URLRequest("1.swf"));
loader1.visible=true;
current=FIRST;

function loader1Compl(event:Event):void
{
    loader2.unloadAndStop(true);
    loader2.visible=false;
    trace("loader2 Unloaded");
}

function loader2Compl(event:Event):void
{
    loader1.unloadAndStop(true);
    loader1.visible=false;
    trace("loader1 Unloaded");
}

function loadSWF(event:LoadEvent):void
{
    if(current == FIRST){
        current=SECOND;
        loader2.load(new URLRequest(event.url));
        loader2.visible=true;
        trace("loader2 Loaded");

    }
    else{
        current=FIRST;
        loader1.load(new URLRequest(event.url));
        loader1.visible=true;
        trace("loader1 Loaded");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you give me some simple code for event listener to unload current SWF?

Comment: sorry for late response, I still dont get it how to run function in main when the child SWF is running by clicking button on child SWF?

Comment: Dispatch the event in the child SWF `dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CLOSE));`. Next, catch this event in the main SWF `loader.content.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);`.

Comment: are you know a way to load dispatchEvent() with parameter.. i think i need parameter if i want to run many SWF

Comment: Yes. Use custom events.

Comment: i already tried but i get new problem... it's possible to load new loader first before unload it? because there's some blink/flash because i unload it first then load it..

Comment: Yes, it is. Use two instances of the `Loader`.

Comment: can you update your answer pls? i already tried but it wont loaded

Comment: thanks.. that's solve my problem.. now i will try to make it custom event

Comment: can you see my update 2? i had problem for custom Event.. did you know what's wrong?

Comment: `if (loader.content)` — this is wrong. Can you upload all sources?

Comment: updated.. it's just blinking because unload first before load it.. even though i load it first then unload it.. thanks for keep hear my problem

Comment: Replace `if (loader.content)` with `if (event.url == "1.swf")`

Comment: i cant do that way because i need to make event.url dinamycally so i tried new way (updated) but it's still blinking

Comment: You shouldn't hide 1st SWF before 2nd SWF loaded. When 2nd loaded you can hide 1st SWF.

Comment: Please, see Update #3.